# Using App Step in 2013 workflow, shows modified by field as "Sharepoint App", how to show the user who actually modified the document?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow

I have created an approval workflow, where I'm using App Step, because previously I'm getting an error like "Item is deleted or locked by one of the user" so, to give elevated permissions, I'm using App Step. Now, the workflow is running good, however, I see that the "Modified By" filed shows "Sharepoint App" instead of the actual user who approved the document or modified, please help.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the SharePoint OOB behavior.** As you know, App steps are used to override the permissions. So, the field "Modified By" got updated as "SharePoint App". There is no option to change "Modified By" field, unless you are assigning permission to the non-permitted item which is used in the Workflows.

**Anyhow try the below custom solution, which deals with the custom "Modified By" field**

> - Create a custom "PeoplePicker" field named "Updated By/Actual Modified By" and make it hidden in the form.
> - Update it every time the workflow ends, with the "WorkflowContext:Initiator".

Note: This solution will provide the WorkFlow Initiator name. If your workflow is not approval WF, then use this solution.